# exclude term in YouTube Data API without including term

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API's [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method to return a list of videos by date. I'm interested in filtering out certain content without having to specify a search term. The documentation specifies that you can use the `-` operator as a Boolean NOT, but this only seems to work if I precede that with a search term, meaning I can do this:

```
q:'food -pizza'
```

which will return results for the query term 'food' but not 'pizza'. Now say I want it to return *any* result excluding pizza you'd think this would work:

```
q:'-pizza'
```

but this returns an empty Array (no results). Am I doing this wrong? is there a way to exclude certain terms without having to specify a specific search term to include before hand?

Comment: I think this is the expected behavior based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). I always see examples like you need to set the `q` parameter value to `boating|sailing -fishing`. You always need to include a term of where to search. You may also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#searching-for-playlists-or-channels) for more information.

Comment: thanks @abielita I've read through the documentation you reference, and like you noticed, the examples always start with a term. that said, the documentation doesn't explicitly state that it **must** start with a term... which is why I asked the question :-/ ...just hoping maybe I missed something... but maybe there's just no way